# Where to place a completionHandler when inside loops?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, completionhandler

I'm using a completionHandler in this function, however it's nested within several for loops (below).  The problem is the handler where it is now gets called every time the loop it's in runs, whereas I only want the handler to pass in the `Set` when the entire function has completed processing.  If I place it outside of the loop, then it gets called too early and is empty.  What should I do here?

Right now when I print to the console to test it prints: 
Set item 1
Set item 1, 2
Set item 1, 2, 3 etc.

```
struct RekoRequest {




    public func getRekos(rekoType: rekoCategory, handler: @escaping (Set<String>) -> Void) {

        var urls = [NSURL]()
        var IDs = Set<String>()


        TwitterRequest().fetchTweets(searchType: "things") { result in


            guard let tweets = result as? [TWTRTweet] else {print("Error in getRekos receiving tweet results from TwitterRequest.fetchTweets"); return}

            for tweet in tweets {





                let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link
                let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
                guard let detect = detector else { print("NSDataDetector error"); return }

                let matches = detect.matches(in: text, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, (text.characters.count)))



                for match in matches {


                    if let url = match.url {

                        guard let unwrappedNSURL = NSURL(string: url.absoluteString) else {print("error converting url to NSURL");return}

                        //Show the original URL
                        unwrappedNSURL.resolveWithCompletionHandler {

                            guard let expandedURL = URL(string: "\($0)") else {print("couldn't covert to expandedURL"); return}


                            guard let urlDomain = expandedURL.host else { print("no host on expandedURL"); return }

                            switch urlDomain {


                            case "www.somesite.com":

                                let components = expandedURL.pathComponents

                                for component in components {
                                    if component == "dp" {
                                        guard let componentIndex = components.index(of: component) else {print("component index error"); return}
                                        let IDIndex = componentIndex + 1
                                        let ID = components[IDIndex]

                                        //Filter out Dups and add to Set
                                        IDs.insert(ID)


                                        handler(IDs) 

                                        print(ID) //this prints multiple sets of IDs, I only want one when the function is finished completely

                                    }
                                }

                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                    } else { print("error with match.url") }

                } //for match in matches loop 




            } //for tweet in tweets loop


        }
    }







}


// Create an extension to NSURL that will resolve a shortened URL
extension NSURL
{
    func resolveWithCompletionHandler(completion: @escaping (NSURL) -> Void)
    {
        let originalURL = self
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: originalURL as URL)
        req.httpMethod = "HEAD"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req as URLRequest)
        {
            body, response, error in completion(response?.url as NSURL? ?? originalURL)
            }
            .resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: why not put the completion handler after the loop?

Comment: When I put it after the loop, I get an empty set

Comment: @GarySabo Where are you inserting into the `IDs` set? Is `setOfIDs` suppose to be `IDs`?

Comment: Sorry I cleaned up the code a bit and missed that, it's `IDs.insert(ID)` in the for component loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your completion handler after the for loop.

```
for component in components {
    if component == "dp" {
        ...
    }
}
handler(IDs)
```

> **Important:** The `handler` should be called *outside* of the for loop, but *within* the `TwitterRequest().fetchTweets()` trailing closure.

---

**Approaches to handling an empty set**

Your `IDs` are being initialized to an empty set. Only after meeting certain conditions within your for loop are values being inserted into this set. If these conditions aren't met, then your `IDs` set will be empty.

If this is undesirable, then you will have to either make changes to your completion handler or alter your conditional logic so that you always get a non-empty set.

One approach might be to have optional set in your callback. Something like:

`(Set<String>?) -> Void`

If `IDs` are empty, then callback with a `nil` and have your calling code handle the possibility of a `nil` set.

Another approach might be to create an enum to encapsulate your result and use this in your callback. Something like:

**Enum**

```
enum Result {
     case success(Set<String>)
     case failure
}
```

**Callback**

`handler: (Result) -> Void`

**Usage**

```
handler(.success(IDs))

// or 

handler(.failure)
```

**Calling Code**

```
getReckos(rekoType: .someType) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let IDs):
        // Use IDs
    case .failure:
       // Handle no IDs
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I may not be articulating it right, but the problem is that that I want the completionHandler to send its result to it's calling function   `RekoRequest().getRekos(rekoType: sometype) { result in` when it's iterated through the loop and is finished, so that I only get 1 completed Set....as of now I am getting a Set each time through the loop i.e. 1, 1 and 2, 1 2 and 3 etc.

Comment: @GarySabo The `handler` needs to be called outside of the for loop. That way, when the loop is finished, then your `handler` will be called once with the `IDs`.

Comment: @GarySabo The additional points in my answer are trying address your comment about the empty set. An empty set is possible with they way you currently have your code written. My answer offers some suggestions on how to handle a potential empty set.

Comment: Thanks, I added my custom extension code which I call `unwrappedNSURL.resolveWithCompletionHandler {`  to my question which get's the full URL from the shorted URL....which I forgot is async, I think this may be the issue I'm getting the multiple handler calls?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't even matter, in the end I am passed the completed set..so I guess the only drawback of my current code is its not as performant as it would be if the handler was only passed after the loop was complete

Comment: @GarySabo The multiple handler calls are occurring because during each iteration of the for loop you are calling the handler. It is not related to the asynchronous call of the `URLSession` data task.

Comment: Got it..ideally what I want is the handler to be placed at the bottom before the } of the fetchTweets trailing closure, that way I can operate on the IDs array inside of the for loops by switching on urlDomain as I am, but with multiple case statements.  Then call the handler to give back the final completed IDs array, however apparently that's not possible in my code? Will still give credit for your great answer though since it answered my original question!